# Best way to obtain ARKit or RealityKit camera rotation?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am writing in Swift and trying to obtain the RealityKit camera's rotation.
I've successfully gotten the position using:

```
xsettings.xcam = arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform.columns.3.x ?? 0);
xsettings.ycam = arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform.columns.3.y ?? 0);
xsettings.zcam = arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform.columns.3.z ?? 0);
```

this works excellently, but I haven't found a rotation solution that seems to work as well.
Currently I am doing this:

```
xsettings.xcamrot =  arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles[0] ?? 0;
xsettings.ycamrot =  arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles[1] ?? 0;
xsettings.zcamrot =  arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles[2] ?? 0;
```

but it doesn't seem to work correctly, there is a lot of weirdness on the roll (eulerAngles[2]) and just some inconsistency overall, at least compared to the positioning which is excellent.
Just curious if there is a better way to access the camera's rotation?

Answer (score 4):

It's not weird. An orientation of ARKit's or RealityKit's camera is expressed as roll (`z`), pitch (`x`), and yaw (`y`). Thus you can easily get right values with expressions you've mentioned earlier:

```
arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.x
arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.y
arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.z
```

***`However, the order of rotation is ZYX`***. Read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407980-eulerangles).

And several words about subscript and dot notation. Each two lines are identical:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.0) {
    // Pitch
    print(arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles[0])  // -0.6444593
    print(arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.x)   // -0.6444593
    // Yaw
    print(arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles[1])  // -0.69380975
    print(arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.y)   // -0.69380975
    // Roll
    print(arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles[2])  // -1.5064332
    print(arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.z)   // -1.5064332
}
```

That's because ARView camera's `eulerAngles` instance property is `SIMD3<Float>` (a.k.a. `simd_float3`) type that supports subscript and dot notation.

On the other hand, ARSCNView pointOfView's `eulerAngles` instance property is `SCNVector3` type that doesn't support subscript but supports dot notation.

P.S.

You don't need to (and can't) assign `a rotation order` explicitly because it's implicit inner rotation mechanism.

Comment: Thank you, I stumbled upon this shortly after posting. It does seem better, but I'm confused, is there a difference between, say, eulerAngles.x and eulerAngles[0]? Or is it, as you say, I had the order wrong?

Comment: Thank you for this, but I guess I need to look further into this, because it is still being "weird", meaning that while the position behaving correctly, I am getting things like having the x.rotation at -31 one frame, and then +31 the next frame.

Comment: 1) It depends on orientation of your virtual World Grid. Each time you launch your AR app a World Grid is oriented differently, because it's built on the very first frame of running ARSession and depends on your device orientation (in real world) at a particular moment. You can't guarantee the same orientation of your device each time your app is launched. For instance: previous time your 3D virtual grid is real-world-North-oriented, but next time it will be real-world-east-oriented. 2) Sometimes (not often) a gimbal lock occurs in iPhone's gyroscope – https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off taking the quaternion for rotation, depending on what you're wanting to do with the output.

You can also use `arView.cameraTransform` to get the camera's transform. From there, translation can be taken from `arView.cameraTransform.translation.{x,y,z}`, and quaternion rotation with `arView.cameraTransform.rotation`. One of the benefits of a quaternion here is that you will not have a problem with rotation order.

If you still wanted to get Euler rotations, you can always use MDLTransform:
`MDLTransform(matrix: self.cameraTransform.matrix).rotation.{x,y,z}`

Comment: This was the most sufficient solution for me. It does not require any math and the rotation can be easily and directly applied to an entity. Still not getting the difference between the currentFrame.camera.transform matrix and arView.cameraTransform…

Comment: I posted a dedicated question for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68193399/what-is-the-difference-between-arview-session-currentframe-camera-transform-and