# What is the difference between arView.session.currentFrame.camera.transform and arview.cameraTransform?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I stumbled upon this while applying **rotation from the camera** onto an entity in RealityKit. I thought I have to do some matrix math to gain the euler angles from `arView.session.currentFrame.camera.transform` matrix, but retrieving the rotation from `arview.cameraTransform.rotation` did the trick (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908038/best-way-to-obtain-arkit-or-realitykit-camera-rotation)).

*So: What is the difference of both matrices and when should be used which?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sample is the `transform matrix` that defines the camera’s rotation/translation in world coordinates.

```
open var transform: simd_float4x4 { get }
```

Your second sample is a specialized type of the `transform matrix`.

```
public var cameraTransform: Transform { get }

// or

@MainActor var cameraTransform: Transform { get }
```

Apple's definition:

> Note that `Transform` is a specialized type that does not support all transformations that can be represented by a general 4x4 matrix. Setting the `Transform` from a 4x4 matrix is a lossy operation. It may result in certain transformations (such as shearing) being dropped!

However, in some situations `cameraTransform` is a more convenient property than `transform`.